# Use $ y= (x-x_0)$ to solve the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use $ y= (x-x_0)^m $ to solve the given differential equation

$ (x+3)^2 y'' - 8(x-1)y' + 14y = 0$

> > Im a bit puzzled by how I simplify into the auxiliary equation after I have plugged in y,y' ,and y"

If...
$ y'=m(x-x_o)^{(m-1)}$

$y''=m(m-1)(x-x_o)^{(m-2)}$

Then I would substitute these into the original equation thats where Im unsure how to simplify the into the auxiliary equation.

Comment: You would have $$(x+3)^2 y'' - 8(x-1)y' + 14y  = 
(x-x_0)^m \left(\dfrac{(m-1) m (x+3)^2}{(x-x_0)^2}+\dfrac{8 m (x-1)}{x_0-x}+14\right) = 0$$ Now, how does that expression equal zero?

Comment: Thanks @Moo The textbook sets the problem equal to zero

Comment: I mean that your next task is to figure out how the product of the two expressions is equal to zero as your next step.